# how do I sort a nested list of ip addresses?

Tags: python, sorting, ip, tcpdump

I have a small list of ip adresses and I would like to sort them by the size of the packets (the integers). How can I sort them?

```
 mylist = [ ["176.20.100.200",176.30.100.255",230], ["176.20.100.100",176.30.100.50",24]  ["172.20.16.80",172.30.16.26",230]]
```

Comment: Can you please provide the exact output your expecting.

Comment: Also, your list is really strange. Is this some typos ? mixture of strings and ints.

Comment: I was expecting to see something like:"  source: 176.20.100.200 dest:176.30.100.255  totalpacketsize: 230 " but with all the ips sorted according to total packet size

Answer (score 0):

Assume your list is as below (fixed typos), you can use sorted with lambda:

```
mylist = [["176.20.100.200","176.30.100.255",230], ["176.20.100.100","176.30.100.50",24], ["172.20.16.80","172.30.16.26",230] ]
for i,j,k in sorted(mylist, key=lambda x:x[2]):
    print ("Source : {}, Destination : {}, totalpacket : {}".format(i,j,k))
```

Output:

```
Source : 176.20.100.100, Destination : 176.30.100.50, totalpacket : 24
Source : 176.20.100.200, Destination : 176.30.100.255, totalpacket : 230
Source : 172.20.16.80, Destination : 172.30.16.26, totalpacket : 230
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this which is pretty pythonic in my opinion:

```
from operator import itemgetter
mylist = [ ["176.20.100.200","176.30.100.255",230], ["176.20.100.100","176.30.100.50",24] ,["172.20.16.80","172.30.16.26",230]]
dict = {}
for index,list in enumerate(sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(2))):
    dict[index] = {'source': list[0], 'dest': list[1], 'packetsize': list[2]  }

print(dict)
```

**Output**

```
{0: {'source': '176.20.100.100', 'dest': '176.30.100.50', 'packetsize': 24}, 1: {'source': '176.20.100.200', 'dest': '176.30.100.255', 'packetsize': 230}, 2: {'source': '172.20.16.80', 'dest': '172.30.16.26', 'packetsize': 230}}}}
```

And now you have all your data in one variable. Access it like any other dictionary.

**NOTE**

It would also be possible to accomplish using lambdas, but lambda functions are slower in small cases like that.

Comment: I think you have succesfully solved the problem with the `sort+itemgetter` and should have stopped there. In my opionion is `[item0, item1, item2, ... ]` more pythonic than `{0: item0, 1:item1, 2:item2, ... }`.

Comment: @VPfB Maybe it is but that is not what the PO was asking. He was clearly asking for something like a dictionnary.

Comment: I have re-read the question again, but it is not that clear to me. I'm still thinking your answer would be very good without the dict of dicts.  Anyway, it's just my comment, nothing more.

Comment: No I thank you for the feedback, but the dictionnary decision came from one if its comment. He expected an output which to me seems like a key/value situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest named tuples. You can treat them like regular tuples, but when you print them, you see what is each value representing.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import itemgetter

Traffic = namedtuple('Traffic', 'source destination packetsize')

mylist = [ 
        Traffic("176.20.100.200","176.30.100.255",2300),
        Traffic("176.20.100.100","176.30.100.50",24),
        Traffic("172.20.16.80","172.30.16.26",230)]

for pkt in sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(2)):
    print(pkt)

# Traffic(source='176.20.100.100', destination='176.30.100.50', packetsize=24)
# Traffic(source='172.20.16.80', destination='172.30.16.26', packetsize=230)
# Traffic(source='176.20.100.200', destination='176.30.100.255', packetsize=2300)
```

Comment: And instead of using the exact same answer I posted and change the data structure, propose an edit, it is there for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it using list comprehension and key with one line

```
  >>> mylist = [ ["176.20.100.200","176.30.100.255",230], ["176.20.100.100","176.30.100.50",24]  ,["172.20.16.80","172.30.16.26",230]]
   >>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda i:i[2])
[['176.20.100.100', '176.30.100.50', 24], ['176.20.100.200', '176.30.100.255', 230], ['172.20.16.80', '172.30.16.26', 230]]
```